# jQuery apply css class to next single element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a simple jquery slideshow. However I am having trouble getting it to loop through the elements.

I know next() just add's the active class to the next elements, and not a single. That is the part i am having trouble with. How can just apply a single class to the next element, and it loop forever.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

var slides = jQuery('#slideshow'); //Parent container for the slideshow
var activeClass = 'active'; //Set the active slide CSS class
var interval = 3000; // Interval in miliseconds
var countSlides = slides.children().length;

//Runs the slideshow
function cycle() {
    slides.children().removeClass(activeClass);
    slides.children().next().addClass(activeClass);
};

setInterval(cycle, interval);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/next/) `.next()` returns the element next to every element in the collection it is called on. In your case that is all children. If you select only the current active element before dropping the `.active` class you can get the element next to it.

```
function cycle() {
    var $current = slides.children('.active');
    $current
        .removeClass('active')
        .next().addClass('active');
}
```

---

Edit: as on how to loop. You need to check if there is a next element. If `.next()` does not return a new element you could grab the first child instead:

```
var $current = slides.children('.active'),
    $next = $current.next();
if (!$next.length) {
   // No next slide, go back to the first one.
   $next = slides.children().first();
}
$current.removeClass('active');
$next.addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked great! Any suggestions on getting it to loop?